# Auto log off windows machine after certain number of minutes

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, windows

I have three machines on my network, two are windows xp and one is windows 7. i would like to have all three machines log a user off if they are on for more than 60 minutes. And I would like this to be applied to the machine not on a per user basis, because I do not want this policy to apply to those users on any other machine. I have installed winexit.scr on one of the machines but the problem is that I cannot change the default value of 10 minutes for the screensaver because that is controlled through group policy, and I cannot seem to find where to change that through group policy on a per machine basis NOT on a per user basis.
If I have left out any details I apologize please let me know anything that is needed

Answer (score 1):

You can setup scheduled task which starts after being idle for certain time and runs `shutdown` standard utility to logoff.

In Control Panel, go to Administrative tasks and invoke Task Scheduler. Create a new task (not simple), trigger it by being Idle and set conditions on appropriate tab. For action choose Start program: `shutdown` with arguments `/l /f`. Save and activate the task.

But be careful - it will run automatically and any unsaved changes in any opened program would be lost.

This way works well under Win2000/2003/2008/Vista/Windows 7. For Win XP you need to use third-party tools, like `PsShutdown` from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx). Add the task in similar way (don't use the wizard but open `Scheduled Task` folder in Explorer and add it manually).